# Localization of redistributable user control library don't works

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, localization, redistributable

I've located a solution consisting of two projects:

1) a **project (startup) "localizzami4.0"** containing with aspx and ascx; there are also resx as local resources 
2) a **project "myUserControlLibrary"** containing the controls (ascx only, no server control); there are also resx as local resources. 
This second project I would like to redistribute, so do not tie it to the namespace of the project "localizzami4.0"

The localization works (copying events with pre-building the ascx under the localizza4.0 \ usercontrols . Ascx and resx from App_LocalResources of MyUserControl in localizzami4.0 \ app_localresoucers); the build action property of the defualt resx file has not been changed (content).

Since, however, I would like to distribute the controls without ascx (only dll), I would like to pre-populate and NOT TICK the option "allow Precompiled site to be updatable", and I begin to have some problems.

I*n order, I did this:* 
0) in "myUserControlLibrary" I created a control "controlloesterno.ascx" with a label "lblSaluto" with value text = "hello" localized (control) in en-gb, es-MX, en-us; 
in "localizzami4.0" I created the page test.aspx ("localizzami4.0") that includes external control (with register assembly);

Forse cercavi: 1) sui resx di "my UserControl Library" impostato la build action dei file su "embedded resource"; il resx di it-it lblSaluto.Text="ciao mondo"; il resx di en-gb lblSaluto.Text="helllo world"; il resx di es-mx lblSaluto.Text="buenas dia"; 2) ho pubblicato il progetto "myUserControlLibrary", generando una cartella c:\mylib\bin con le dll e i file .config; nella bin, ho tante sottocartelle (con dentro la dll del resx corrispondente alla cultura) per quante culture localizzo, e poi le dll della libreria e dei controlli singoli (se uso o meno il merge degli assembly in output) [di questo ne sono certo perché ho decompilato le dll e ne ho visto il contenuto] 3) ho copiato il contenuto della c:\mylib\bin della libreria "myUserControlLibrary" sotto la bin del progetto 1) "localizzami4.0\bin" 4)ho impostato  nel web.config di "localizzami4.0" 5) premuto F5 :)

1) on resx "myUserControlLibrary" set the build action of files to "embedded resource"; 
    in resx it-IT lblSaluto.Text = "ciao mondo"; 
    in resx en-gb lblSaluto.Text = "helllo world"; 
    in resx es-mx lblSaluto.Text = "buenas dia";

2) I published the project "myUserControlLibrary", creating a folder c: \ mylib \ bin directory with the dll and the config file.; in the bin, I have many subfolders (with the dll in the corresponding culture resx) to localize many cultures, and then the dll library and controls individual (whether or not to use the merge assembly output) [of this I am sure because I decompiled the dll and I've seen the content]

3) I copied the contents of c: \ mylib \ bin library "myUserControlLibrary" under the bin directory of the project: 1) "localizzami4.0 \ bin"

4) I set  in web.config "localizzami4.0"

5) press F5 :)

The value of the label lblSaluto that I expect is: hello wordl instead read "buongiorno" or as if it had not used the location; I do not even out "ciao mondo".

I searched on the internet, on msdn, I find walkthroug generic, or location of a single project or user control redistributable libraries but not localized.

Has anyone done something like this or knows a link or post to which I can refer?

thanks